# Facebook notifications from friends not in any lists

Tags: facebook, notifications, status, friend-list

I've started getting notifications, just this week, from some of my friends when they update a status on Facebook. Everywhere I look, people say "these are your close friends, turn off the notifications on that list", but my close friends list is *empty*.

I turned the notifications off anyway, and it continues to spam me. I have also deselected notifications for all other updates under the notifications options.

It is driving me crazy! How can I get it to stop?

Comment: Try adding one friend as a "close friend" and see if everyone else's notifications disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the notification tab on top of Facebook page (the World looking one). Put your mouse over the notification spam. Click the `x` on the top right of that notification. Then click turn off. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It worked perfectly for me... http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-tip-disable-close-friends-notifications-remove-friends-close-friends-list/